# How to add middleware to a group of routes in Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js

According to the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#middleware): The middleware will be executed in series in this order:

- nuxt.config.js
- Matched layouts
- Matched pages

Now I was wondering how I can add middleware to a group of pages in a slug like this:

```
pages/
--| _slug/
-----| comments.vue
-----| index.vue
```

Some options I think there are:

1) I could add the middleware to every individual page in the directory but that's not dry.

2) Another solution would be to add the middleware to the `nuxt.config.js` with a conditional on the route, but that doesn't feel like the right place for that code either, besides that it would run on any other route too.

3) I could maybe use nested routes with a template containing only a single `<nuxt-child>` element, but I'm not sure about the side effects: Can I still use page-component properties? Does that nest everything in another DOM element?.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok just figured my 'option 3' is the way to go here:

Create a file `_slug.vue` and add it to pages at the same nesting level as the `_slug/` directory:

```
pages/
--| _slug/
-----| comments.vue
-----| index.vue
--| _slug.vue
```

Add the middleware property in that `_slug.vue` file:

```
<template>
  <nuxt-child/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  middleware: 'myslugmiddleware',
}
</script>
```

Comment: how do I redirect an index.vue to _slug.vue if my index.vue is located right inside pages

Comment: You have to add a param named `slug` (without the underscore) in the link: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html